# When flagging a flag as invalid, report which flag was flagged as invalid

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, flagging, flag-history

When you flag a flag as invalid, the flag history doesn't report which flag was flagged as invalid.

[image: screenshot]

It would be helpful if the flag history would report which flag was flagged as invalid.

Comment: my only invalid flag is shown. Did it happen more than once? Maybe it was a bug

Comment: When I flag another flag as invalid, my flag history doesn't report which flag I have flagged, and it has never shown that.

Comment: Could you use some variation on the word 'flag' a bit more?  It's a little too easy to follow as it is. :P

Comment: It's easier than "If a woodchuck would chuck wood, how much wood would a woodchuck chuck?"

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but I really want to give you a +1 just for the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we no longer use valid/invalid on flags, I'm going to status-norepro this so this no longer lingers as an active feature request.